# prime number and sum of cubes in c

Tags: c, scanf, primes

I am trying to figure out how to get the prime number n, and calculate the sum of cubes for that `n` `(1^3 + 2^3 + ... + n^3)`. So far I can figure out how to get the primes. I just can't figure out how to get that same n to calculate its primes. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, c = 0
    printf("Enter any number n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=2; i<=n/2; i++){
        if(n%i == 0){
        c=1;
        break;
        }
    }
    if (c==0)
        printf(%d is a prime number.",n);
    else
        printf("%d is not a prime number.",n);
    printf("Enter that same number n: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int num, cube, sum = 0, j=1;
    while (j <= num) {
        cube = j*j*j;
        sum = sum + cube;
        j++;
    }
    printf("sum of cubes of %d is %d\n", num, sum);

    return 0:
}
```

I get an error on the second scanf because it says num is undeclared. What should I do to fix this situation.

Comment: `%num`--> seriously?

Comment: By declaring `num`

Comment: i meant to put &num

Comment: Your first error is at line 4.

Comment: It says "num" is undeclared because you declared it *after* you attempted to use it (`int num` occurs after the `scanf`). That should be obvious.

Comment: Lot's of compile errors. Did you retyped the program in the question instead of copy/pasting it?

Comment: Not related to your question: but why does the user need to enter the same number again? Use the input from the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Use scanf after declaring int num. Also you have used % in 2nd num. Use

```
int num, cube, sum = 0, j=1;
scanf("%d", &num);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d", %num);
int num, cube, sum = 0, j=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this starting piece

```
long double sumcubs(int n)
{
    int i;
    long double ret = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        ret += (i * i * i);

    return ret;
}
```

Once you have encapsulated this sum of cubes function, it should become easier to organize and write the rest of your code.